# Should I inherit the class logger when using NLog?

Tags: c#, nlog

When logging from a derived class, should I inherit the class-logger instance from the base class, or instantiate a new one? 
Namely, which is better:

```
public class Base
{
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private void Foo()
    {
        _logger.Info("Hello world");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    new private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private void Fee()
    {
        _logger.Info("Hello world");
    }
}
```

or:

```
public class Base
{
    protected static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private void Foo()
    {
        _logger.Info("Hello world");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    private void Fee()
    {
        _logger.Info("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a new one.

`LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger` creates a logger whose name is the current class. If you use the parent's class logger, you lose the information of the class doing the logging, it would appear as if the logging was done by the parent class. Most of the time, you want as precise an information as possible when logging.

Comment: Update: Actually they (NLog) adress this in their Tutorial. See: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#expose-logger-to-sub-classes

Comment: Thanks @Fildor for the doc link. It's helpful.

Comment: The content in the linked document of @Fildor has changed. The new link is https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-create-Logger-for-sub-classes

Comment: And it looks like it's been edited again. Right now it has an alternative pattern too. I took the liberty of posting another answer with the other pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I think Falanwe's answer was probably the only correct one at the time of posting. However the [NLog wiki now suggests](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-create-Logger-for-sub-classes) an alternative pattern as well:

```
public class Base
{
    protected Base()
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType().ToString());
    }

    protected Logger _logger { get; private set; }

    private void Foo()
    {
        _logger.Info("Hello world");
    }
}

class ExactClass : BaseClass
{
    public ExactClass() : base() { }

    private void Fee()
    {
        _logger.Info("Hello world");
    }
}
```

IMHO there are pros and cons

- *Pro:* There's less code in the subclasses (DRY).
- *Con:* The logger is not static so each instance creates its own logger. The [NLog best practices](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial#Best-practices-for-using-NLog) says "Creating a new Logger has a small overhead, as it has to acquire locks and allocate objects".